# Qt Android в Linux

Tags: android, c++, linux, qt

Можно ли писать приложения под Android на c++ с qt в Linux и какие для этого нужны компоненты?

Comment: Qt и эмулятор адройда

Answer (score 0):

Можно. Нужно скачать с сайта qt.io онлайн инсталлятор. Запустить его, и в настройках выбрать все что связано с android, тем самым появятся компиляторы для android. Потом вроде даже настроек не надо делать, выбираешь какие профили для разработки нужны и всё.

Comment: Еще довольно древний NDK (и SDK, кажется, тоже).